# Find the number of possible integers $m$ such that equation $x = \sqrt{2x - m}$ has solutions in $[-1, 3]$. Do I need to verify if $x ≥ \frac{m}{2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the number of possible integers $m$ such that equation $x = \sqrt{2x - m}$ has solutions in $[-1, 3]$.

My solution:

$x = \sqrt{2x - m}$

⟺$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x ≥ 0  \\ 
x ≥ \frac{m}{2} \\ 
x^2  - 2x = - m
\end{array}
\right. 
$

Based on the graph of $f(x) = x^2 - 2x$,

$-1 ≤ f(x)  ≤ 3$ for $x ∈ [0, 3]$

$⟹ m ∈ [-3, 1]$ or $m ∈ \text{{-3, -2, -1, 0, 1}} \qquad (*)$

Since $x ≥ 0$, it is straighforward that the condition $x ≥ \frac{m}{2}$ holds for $m$ being $-3, -2, -1, or\; 0$.

With $m = 1$, $x = 1 ≥ \frac{m}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$

So there are $5$ possible values of $m$.

---

The solution in my textbook doesn't verify the condition $x ≥ \frac{m}{2}$ after it reaches $(*)$, so I supposed it's not necessary, but I struggled to see why. Please advise.

Thank you!

Comment: Stick with your instincts, all relevant conditions must be checked.  Maybe they had a quick way to do it, but even in that case they ought to point it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an oversight in the textbook, IMO, if they don't say anything. One could argue that since $x^2-2x = -m$ is true, it follows that $ 0 \le x^2 = 2x-m$ and so the condition you checked can be shown this way.

But not mentioning anything at all is an oversight, because the moment you start having 2 radical terms in an equation and you sqare one side, you might get terms that are not a priori known to be non-negative (as $x^2$ is).